# How to stop spark streaming when the data source has run out

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job that read from Kafka every 5 seconds, does some transformation on incoming data, and then writes to the file system.

This doesn't really need to be a streaming job, and really, I just want to run it once a day to drain the messages onto the file system.  I'm not sure how to stop the job though.

If I pass a timeout to the streamingContext.awaitTermination, it doesn't stop the process, all it does is cause the process to spawn errors when it comes time to iterate on the stream (see error below)

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do

this is for Spark 1.6 on Python

EDIT:

thanks to @marios the solution was this:

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(10)
ssc.stop()
```

that runs the script for ten seconds before stopping.

simplified code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Vehicle Data Consolidator").set('spark.files.overwrite','true')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(
    ssc,
    kafkaParams["zookeeper.connect"],
    "vehicle-data-importer",
    topicPartitions,
    kafkaParams)

stream.saveAsTextFiles('stream-output/kafka-vehicle-data')

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(10)
```

error:

```
16/01/29 15:05:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1454097944200 in memory on localhost:58960 (size: 3.0 MB, free: 48.1 MB)
16/01/29 15:05:44 WARN BlockManager: Block input-0-1454097944200 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/01/29 15:05:44 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1454097944200
16/01/29 15:05:45 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1454097945000 ms
py4j.Py4JException: Cannot obtain a new communication channel
    at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:232)
    at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:111)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonTransformedDStream.compute(PythonDStream.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:246)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
16/01/29 15:05:45 INFO MemoryStore: Block input-0-1454097944800 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.0 MB, free 466.1 MB)
16/01/29 15:05:45 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1454097944800 in memory on localhost:58960 (size: 3.0 MB, free: 45.1 MB)
```

Comment: How could you know the data source is out? By the way, you can call `ssc.stop()` after `ssc.awaitTermination` to stop the Streaming application.

Comment: IMHO, if you just need to read the data once in a day then create a Spark Batch job to read and process the data and further use some scheduler like cron or Quartz to schedule your job.

Comment: The problem with executing a single batch (using createRDD) is that there is no easy way to track the offsets within zookeeper.  THat's one of the things I'd like to achieve here

Comment: I'd considered calling `ssc.stop` but I was having trouble figuring out how to call it asynchronously

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that the right method to call is [awaitTerminationOrTimeout](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py#L210)(self, timeout).

I am not sure if it also stops the streaming context. So maybe you can call a ssc.stop() right after the timeout ends.

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(10)
ssc.stop()
```

**Note:** Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31116817/1553233) for a similar question.

Comment: If you find a dupe flag it.

Comment: This is not exactly duplicated (but can be relevant to someone). The problem there how to stop the streaming socket not to turn down the entire spark context. Also the problem there was on a twitter context running in Scala and not on Kafka running on pyspark.

Comment: Then maybe a comment is more suitable if this is not the answer

Comment: This was the correct answer. `ssc.awaitTermination(10)` blocks script execution but doesn't actually stop the streaming context.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try Kafka "consumer.timeout.ms" parameter, which will gracefully end KafkaReceiver.(from [kafka 0.8 configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html))

> Throw a timeout exception to the consumer if no message is available
>   for consumption after the specified interval

```
HDF = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, topics={strLoc : 1}, kafkaParams={"consumer.timeout.ms":"20000" }, zkQuorum='xxx:2181', groupId='xxx-consumer-group')
```

You will not able to receive any new kafka messages in current streaming execution and always get empty RDDs.
And check the count of empty RDDs in DSteam.foreachRDD(func). Terminate streaming exectuion if you continurously get empty RDDs.

Comment: tried this:

`kafkaParams = {
    "metadata.broker.list": str.join(',',brokers),
    "zookeeper.connect": str.join(',',zkNodes),
    "consumer.id": "vehicle-data-importer",
    "group.id":"importers",
    "auto.offset.reset": "smallest",
    "consumer.timeout.ms": "10000"
}`

there was no effect

Comment: "consumer.timeout.ms" will not stop streaming execution but will terminate the kafka receiver to wait for more messages even new message arrived later.   you can simply use "ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(10)" but it is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here spark 1.6 onwards the ssc.stop call in the same thread as the Dstream processing thread would create a deadlock as stop would wait for poller  thread to complete creating deadlock.sp the call for stop from another thread